# can't complete login to ubuntu after editing pulseaudio scripts

Tags: pulseaudio, 19.10

I was having some issues with switching my audio output (ie I plug in HDMI, if an application is currently running its audio through the computer's speakers, the audio does not move to the HDMI unless I kill the pulseaudio session and restart the program) and tried adding some scripts that run at login but can't remember what they are (not smart).  I know I put, for example, `pulseaudio -k` somewhere.

Anyway, I get to a login screen as usual but after I enter my credentials it flashes the dell screen then goes right back to login. I can login using the terminal. I am certain that I broke my system when adding these custom scripts as something related to them comes up after I login using the terminal.

I just want to basically reset my desktop without losing my files, and perhaps internet bookmarks, as I have given up on trying to see where the offending code is, but if there is an easy way to find this then I'm all ears. Maybe there is a way, for example, to restore my desktop to its factory settings from the terminal without touching my documents?

```
Ubuntu 19.10 PHILLIP-Precision-5520 tty

PHILLIP-Precision-5520 login: PHILLIP Password:
Last login: Sun Apr 19 13:46:31 EDT 2020 on tty4 Welcome to Ubuntu 19.10 (GNU/Linux 5.3.0-46-generic x86_64)

* Management:
* Support:
* Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com https://landscape.canonical.com https://ubuntu.com/advantage
0 updates can be installed immediately.

0 of these updates are security updates.
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
Failed to kill PulseAudio daemon.
Toggling output devices (Speakers/Headset) No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.

No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
No PulseAudio daemon running, or not running as session daemon.
Moving input: to sink:
Setting default sink to:
Can't open display E: (pulseaudio) main.c: Failed to kill daemon: No such process PHILLIP (master #) $ ==
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, `pactl list sinks` This command shows you what are the priorities and running outputs. Or copy your home directory to a USB stick and reinstall everything, afterward you can restore your documents.

Answer (score 1):

I may present you two workarounds. Please tell me and all the readers in the comments how it worked.

## Reset pulseaudio

You can reset prrograms to default settings, by purging them and then reinstall:

```
sudo apt purge pulseaudio
sudo apt install pulseaudio
```

## Second user

If you create a new user, all the settings from your old user are not loaded.

```
sudo adduser user2
```

If you want to be admin, just enter

```
sudo adduser user2 sudo
```

You then can copy them. For example the Firefox settings: (please change the *user1* and *unser2*)

```
ls /home/user1/.mozilla/firefox/
```

There you can find your profile folder let say it's called *abcdefgh.default*. Then you can copy them by (you may cange

```
sudo cp /home/user1/.mozilla/firefox/abcdefgh.default /home/user2/.mozilla/firefox/myprofile
```

After you login as *user2* you can start firefox by

```
firefox -P
```

to "create" a new profile based on the copied folder.

Other programms you have to try how to copy the setting. Please check the hidden files on your homefolder. Expexially the *.config* folder.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Really good suggestion about adding a second user. This ran into the same problem, unfortunately. I tried removing pulseaudio, still same issue.  I don't think there's anything wrong with pulseaudio, I think the issue is when I was looking through the forums and trying some random workarounds, I ended up adding some bad code to a file that is not directly related to pulseaudio.

Comment: have you edited these files via the terminal? Then I suggest you to check `history` and review your last commands (in the fike $HISTFILE saved)

Comment: I did edit via terminal, but more than 500 commands ago which is the max history I'm able to view.

Comment: I got an other idea. With `find /etc -mtime 5` you get a list of all files changed 5 days ago. perhaps you can find there something helpfull.

Comment: Good suggestion, digging into that now. I've tried a bunch of files but haven't seen it yet but I'm still digging. In the meantime - do you  know how to look at the scripts that ubuntu runs at startup:? There is a place in the gui to tell it to run a custom script at startup. I think I have skype set to run automatically, for example. I vaguely remember putting something in there too.

Comment: You got two different "autostarts". The first ones start with the system (graphical Interface, Network, mounting, etc) and the others come with the Login (desktop enviroment, skype and other applications). I recommend you to look for some question here on AskUbuntu. You're wellcome to poste the Links to the helpfull ones

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it. I did a search for 'pulseaudio -k' in my '/etc' folder and found the offending files in '/etc/profile.d'. I had dropped some scripts in there. I deleted those, rebooted and problem solved. Thanks to all who have chimed in.